# How can i run sql server script with c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm write this code for run sql server script:

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=behzad;Integrated Security=True";
//string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("d:\\behzadBULK.sql");
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

but this line :

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
```

i get this error:

```
 Are you missing reference?
```

what reference should be add to the project?

Comment: Use `using System.Data.SqlClient;` on namespace section..

Comment: See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I added using System.Data.SqlClient; but so get up error!

Comment: What reference does it show in the error ?

Comment: error is:The type or namespace name 'Server' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\behzad Folder\RAREPORT\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs 35 13 WindowsFormsApplication3

Comment: Just install the reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` in your project, if its not present now. And add a namespace for it in your code this should do it

Comment: thanks for help me my friend,but how can i install the that reference?

Comment: Right click on your project and click on Add Reference. After that a window will open where you can see list of assemblies available Search for the above one or browse for it online in that window. And then add it.

Comment: Please post your solution to i can vote up.

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi - I just added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` is missing and that's why that error is popping up.

You can resolve it by just adding a reference to your project for that particular assembly by right clicking your project and clicking on add reference. That should open a window to show you all the assemblies available and from there you can choose this assembly and add it to your project.

After that, make sure you have added the namespace for it in your code and that should do it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using SQLclient Connection Not SqlServer

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

and Some code like this

```
settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyTweetConnection"];
ConnectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
SQLCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
```